# I'm writing a load test script and able to successfully run with 1st request but not able to do 2nd req and Session-Timeout error with 403 error code

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have added the Cookie Manager and tried.The first request is success and 2nd request was failed with timeout

[image: Test Plan]

Please help me

Comment: Can you please post the complete request that is failing ? You probably need to store and pass a token, session id, or something like that.

Comment: Actually ,I'm extracting CSRF token and adding to the request

Comment: Please post the response from the Login request so we can determine what else might be wrong.  Maybe there is a Viewstate, EventValidation, or another value that needs to be captured and passed.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you recorded something which acts like a session identifier and it's hard-coded when it's supposed to be dynamic like when you're logging in you're getting a dynamic parameter which identifies the session.

So you need to perform the [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of this session identifier.

The easiest way of detecting the dynamic parameters is recording the same user action again and compare the resulting JMeter test plans, all values which have changed need to be correlated - extracted from the previous response using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and stored into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Once you replace hard-coded dynamic parameters with the respective JMeter Variables you test should start working as expected.

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)